# maven web.xml The element type "web-app" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</web- app>"

Tags: java, web.xml

Eclipse Java EE IDE
Apache Tomcat v9.0
I created the project by New->Maven Project, and select the Maven archetype as maven-archetype-webapp.
web.xml content is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>WebProject</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-class>com.wise.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

project structure in eclipse as below

[image: eclipse web.xml]
there are two errors:
The element type "web-app" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'display-name'. One of '{"http://
 java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":servlet-class, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":jsp-file, "http://java.sun.com/
 xml/ns/javaee":init-param, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":load-on-startup, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/
 javaee":enabled, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":async-supported, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/
 javaee":run-as, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":security-role-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/
 javaee":multipart-config}' is expected.

Anyone can give some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this header and try

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
```

and add the header schema reference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: ,still fails and shows The element type "web-app" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</web-app>".

Answer (score 0):

Your web.xml structure should be like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>WebProject</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-class>com.wise.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: ,it still fails and comes 2 errors.first is :The element type "web-app" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</web-app>".

Comment: another error :cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'display-name'. One of '{"http://
 java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":servlet-class, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":jsp-file, "http://java.sun.com/
 xml/ns/javaee":init-param, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":load-on-startup, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/
 javaee":enabled, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":async-supported, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/
 javaee":run-as, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":security-role-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/
 javaee":multipart-config}' is expected.

Comment: This web.xml is generated with Eclipse->Dynamic Web project and it is working in current project.

Comment: Which server you are using?

Comment: I create the project using Maven Project and select the Maven archetype as maven-archetype-webapp. Using Apache Tomcat v9.0

Comment: I did the same thing and it is working fine with below generated code.                                  <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>

Answer (score 0):

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
</blink>
```